# how to display the two pictures in same column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to column the two pictures?

this is my code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"><img src="download.png" /></div>
  <div class="col-6"><img src="oroquieta-city.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're including the bootstrap.css files at the top of your HTML?

Comment: those will stack column on top of column already? do you mean same row or want two pictures in one column as in two img tags?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Your current code gives you two columns side by side in one row (if the screen is large enough to display it). To make sure that the images are always one on top of the other, you would add a second *row* so that the rows stack on top of each other.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"><img src="download.png" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"><img src="oroquieta-city.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add bootstrap file link or bootstrap CDN link.. below example.. it when i added the link. thanks

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"><img src="download.png" /></div>
  <div class="col-6"><img src="oroquieta-city.png" /></div>
</div>
```